# Find UTF-8 strings in all files under a directory

Tags: python, perl, bash

How can I recursively search for all files under a directory that contain a regex pattern? The pattern is UTF-8 string.

Any solution using Python, Perl or bash is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -lr "pattern" /mydirectory/*
```

It will list all the files of mydirectory where pattern found .

Answer (score 2):

Python solution that use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os
import re

target_dir = '.'
pattern = re.compile(r'blah')

for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(target_dir):
    for fn in filenames:
        filepath = os.path.join(parent, fn)
        try:
            with open(filepath) as f:
                if any(pattern.search(line) for line in f):
                    print(filepath)
        except IOError:
            pass
```